# Quarkus Multi-modules project live reload

Tags: quarkus, multi-module

I have a simple multi-module Quarkus project. The live-reload works great if I changed the quick-start-rest, while it failed with some exceptions similar to the "cannot find symbol" if I changed the quick-start-rest.

Comment: Please clarify. In both cases you changed quick-start-rest? And once it worked and once it failed? Live reload is not always working in my experience, but even when it only works sometimes it is great.

Comment: quick-start-rest is the main application module and quick-start-core is a shared module. I made any changes in quick-start-rest after I start the application, and the live coding works. If I made any changes in quick-start-core, then the exceptions similar to the "cannot find symbol" will be raised.